# How to write findall without permutations?

Tags: prolog

I want to write a program which evaluates, which item combinations can be carried within a specific bag capacity. The important part of the program is to kick out all permutations of possibilities. The program should give out every possibility once and not their permutations. Here an example query:

```
?- place(Possibility, 2).
Possibility = [water];
Possibility = [flower];
Possibility = [paper];
Possibility = [meat];
Possibility = [wood];
Possibility = [glass];
Possibility = [water, flower];
Possibility = [water, paper];
Possibility = [flower, paper].
```

My code so far is:

```
% item(Name, Space)
item(water, 1).
item(flower, 1).
item(paper, 1).
item(meat, 2).
item(wood, 2).
item(glass, 2).
item(stone, 3).
item(gold, 3).
item(metal, 3).
item(platin, 4).

% maximum capacity of bag
maxcapacity(10).

place(Possibility, Capacity) :-
    maxcapacity(MaxCapacity),
    between(1, MaxCapacity, Capacity),
    possibilities(Capacity, [], Possibility).

possibilities(Capacity, Acc, Acc) :-
    \+ (space(Possibility, [], 0, Capacity), sort(Possibility, SortedPossibility), \+ member(SortedPossibility, Acc)).
possibilities(Capacity, Acc, PossibilityList) :-
    space(Possibility, [], 0, Capacity),
    sort(Possibility, SortedPossibility),
    not(member(SortedPossibility, Acc)),
    Acc1 = [SortedPossibility|Acc],
    possibilities(Capacity, Acc1,PossibilityList).

space(Acc, Acc, Space, MaxCapacity) :-             
    Space =< MaxCapacity,
    Acc \= [].
space(Possibility, Acc, Space, MaxCapacity) :-
    item(Item, ItemSpace),
    not(member(Item, Acc)),
    NewSpace is Space + ItemSpace,
    NewSpace =< MaxCapacity,
    Acc1 = [Item|Acc],
    space(Possibility, Acc1, NewSpace, MaxCapacity).
```

I tried to kick out permutations by sorting, but the program still gives me all permutations and puts the item combinations somehow in a list. The program should work as in the example query above.

I would really appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Your example query doesn't work with your code: The query is for a predicate `space/2`, but you only define `space/4`. There is a `place/2`, but it also behaves differently from what you show.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was "place(Possibility, 2)". I edited my post.

Comment: I misunderstood your "example query". I thought you meant to say that it's an example of how your program behaves, but it was an example of how you would like it to behave. Maybe you could edit the post to clarify this a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your program is creating possibility lists, not possibilities. The code below instead finds a possibility, then backtracks to find the next possibility.

`possibilities(_, Current, Current)` unifies the current working possibility with the query, to return the current possibility as a result. `Current \= []` is used to eliminate the empty bag as a possibility (based on your expected results).

After backtracking, `possibilities(Capacity, [], Possibility)` is used to find the initial element in the bag. The first item that fits in the bag will be chosen, and we recurse (first to the unification clause above, then to the partially full bag clause below). Once all possibilities have been exhausted with this item in the bag, we backtrack and find the next item that will fit.

`possibilities(Capacity, [Current|Rest], Possibility)` essentially operates in the same manner as `possibilities(Capacity, [], Possibility)`, but with one additional check to ensure that we only get possibilities in alphabetical order, to eliminate permutations. This then recurses as above.

(As a side note, if you want to be able to store, say, two water in a bag, simply change `A @< Current` to `A @=< Current`).

```
item(water, 1).
item(flower, 1).
item(paper, 1).
item(meat, 2).
item(wood, 2).
item(glass, 2).
item(stone, 3).
item(gold, 3).
item(metal, 3).
item(platin, 4).

% maximum capacity of bag
maxcapacity(10).

place(Possibility, Capacity) :-
    maxcapacity(MaxCapacity),
    between(1, MaxCapacity, Capacity),
    possibilities(Capacity, [], Possibility).

possibilities(_, Current, Current) :- 
    Current \= [].

possibilities(Capacity, [], Possibility) :-
    item(A, B),
    B =< Capacity,
    NewCapacity is Capacity - B,
    possibilities(NewCapacity, [A], Possibility).

possibilities(Capacity, [Current|Rest], Possibility) :-
    item(A, B),
    B =< Capacity,
    NewCapacity is Capacity - B,
    A @< Current,
    possibilities(NewCapacity, [A,Current|Rest], Possibility).
```

Answer (score 1):

You're already most of the way there with your `space/4` predicate, but then you layer on extra things in `possibilities/3`, which "puts the item combinations somehow in a list" although you don't want that.

So let's look at an example of `space/4` directly:

```
?- space(Possibility, [], 0, 2).
Possibility = [water] ;
Possibility = [flower, water] ;
Possibility = [paper, water] ;
Possibility = [flower] ;
Possibility = [water, flower] ;
Possibility = [paper, flower] ;
Possibility = [paper] ;
Possibility = [water, paper] ;
Possibility = [flower, paper] ;
Possibility = [meat] ;
Possibility = [wood] ;
Possibility = [glass] ;
false.
```

Note that you get solutions of capacity 1 as well as solutions of capacity 2. Your use of `maxcapacity/1` and `between/3` suggests to me that you would *only* want solutions of capacity *exactly* 2 here. You can change the `=<` to `=` in the first clause of `space/4` to get this:

```
?- space(Possibility, [], 0, 2).
Possibility = [flower, water] ;
Possibility = [paper, water] ;
Possibility = [water, flower] ;
Possibility = [paper, flower] ;
Possibility = [water, paper] ;
Possibility = [flower, paper] ;
Possibility = [meat] ;
Possibility = [wood] ;
Possibility = [glass] ;
false.
```

Now we can eliminate permutations in *each* solution separately rather than, as you did, collect *all* solutions in a list and try to work with that, which is more difficult.

Eliminating unwanted permutations means choosing a representative permutation and ignoring all others. For example, we can choose a strictly increasing (i.e., alphabetically ordered) permutation as the representative:

```
?- space(Possibility, [], 0, 2), increasing(Possibility).
Possibility = [flower, water] ;
Possibility = [paper, water] ;
Possibility = [flower, paper] ;
Possibility = [meat] ;
Possibility = [wood] ;
Possibility = [glass] ;
false.
```

The `increasing/1` predicate can be defined as follows:

```
increasing([]).
increasing([_]).
increasing([X,Y|Xs]) :-
    X @< Y,
    increasing([Y|Xs]).
```

With this, you can throw away your `possibilities/3` predicate and generalize the query above to put into your definition of `place/2`.